# WPF: How to delete row in grid by button in one of cells of row?

Tags: c#, wpf

It's a code for adding one more row with four elements:

```
private void ItemAdd(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button deleteButton = new Button { Visibility = Visibility.Visible, Content = "X" };
    TextBox itemName = new TextBox { MinHeight = 10, MaxHeight = 40 };
    TextBox weight = new();
    Label number = new Label();
    RowDefinition row = new()
    { Height = GridLength.Auto, MinHeight = 10 };
    currentRow = row;
    NamesList.RowDefinitions.Add(row);
    number.Content = GetCurrentRowIndex(NamesList, row) - 1;
    AddAt(NamesList, number, GetCurrentRowIndex(NamesList, row), 0);
    AddAt(NamesList, itemName, GetCurrentRowIndex(NamesList, row), 1);
    AddAt(NamesList, weight, GetCurrentRowIndex(NamesList, row), 2);
    AddAt(NamesList, deleteButton, GetCurrentRowIndex(NamesList, row), 3);
/*also i have this for deleting row, but next going method that not work*/
        void DeleteCurrentRow(Grid grid, RowDefinition row)
        {
            grid.RowDefinitions.Remove(row);
        }
}
```

i tryed to insert variable for hypothetical current row
`RowDefinition currentRow;`
But it no work

Answer (score 0):

The `RowDefinition` is just a layout object that describes the layout of the `Grid`. It does not map to actual elements or a rendered grid row. `RowDefinition` tells the `Grid` that it has a row with specific attributes - it's a descriptor. In tandem with the attached property `Grid.Row` it tells the `Grid` how to arrange its child elements. If you remove the definition the elements are still a child of `Grid` and therefore visible - you only have removed the layout arrangement.

Unless you track the elements by their row index e.g., by using a map, you must filter the `Grid.Children` collection by querying the attached `Grid.Row` property:

```cs
void DeleteCurrentRow(Grid grid, RowDefinition rowDefinition)
{
  // Consider to pass in the row index instead of the RowDefinition object
  int indexOfRowToRemove = grid.RowDefinitions.IndexOf(rowDefinition);
  IEnumerable<UIElement> rowElements = grid.Children
    .Cast<UIElement>()
    .Where(element => Grid.GetRow(element) == indexOfRowToRemove);
  
  foreach (var rowElement in rowElements)
  {
    grid.Children.Remove(rowElement);
  }
}
```

If you have to work with a data table, you should prefer the `DataGrid`. The `Grid` is meant to arrange UI elements for the UI layout and not to show data. Inserting and removing rows is also more straight forward. This is because the `DataGrid` was designed with dynamic data in mind.

In WPF you always prefer to create layout in XAML, because it is so much easier. You can't learn WPF and avoid XAML. You will regret when you start to learn XAML later.

Comment: so thankfull for it, i think i should rework my project

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this could/should work

This is my column for the buttons:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Click="DiscardChanges" Tag="{Binding }">Discard Changes</Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This is my grid init

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DatGrdNewEmployee" ItemsSource="{Binding}" d:ItemsSource="{d:SampleData}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

And this is my method. Since I don't quite know how you store your items and if there is a view involved, I just left the part where you'll have to add your removal code commented. It's just better to remove the items from a list then to try and tell wpf to get rid of a specific row

```
private void DiscardChanges(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var myVal = ((Button)sender).DataContext;

    if (myVal is Employee emp)
    {
        //remove emp from your List
    }
}
```